# If-IE mixin isn't passing CSS validator

Tags: css, validation, internet-explorer, sass, mixins

So I'm pretty new to front end developing. I'm following a course for about 4 a 5 months now. But I'm a bit stuck with a IE mixin. The mixin if-IE mixin works great, see:

```
@mixin if-ie {
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
    @content;
 }
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active {
    @content;
 }
}
```

But when I check the css output in the W3C validator it spits out 3 errors:

- Unknown dimension 0\0
- Parse Error ) { .transparent { fill: #FFC0CB; }}
- Feature -ms-high-contrast doesn't exist for media all
  ),(-ms-high-contrast: active) { .transparent { fill: #FFC0CB; } }

I have seen other developers use this type of mixin on the internet and my colleagues even use it at work. So I have 2 questions:

1. Why are so many people using this when it isn't valid CCS?
2. Is there a way to make this mixin valid CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your parse error: a parenthesis should be closed at the end of the second selector:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  /* */
}
```

They're hacks.
First rule of CSS hacks is you shouldn't use them.
Second rule is if you really need them, well, choose ones that are considered a bit more robust than UA string detection, like the ones at [BrowserHacks](http://browserhacks.com):

> Reminder!
>   Please keep in mind using a hack is not always the perfect solution. It can be useful to fix some weird browser specific bug, but in most cases you should fix your CSS/JS or use [feature detection](http://modernizr.com).

Hacks are mainly based on some parse error from some version(s) of a browser like `0\0` or non standard properties like `-ms-high-contrast`. Valid CSS is recognized as expected by modern browsers so you can't use *that* to apply a style to some browsers and not others.

> 1.Why are so many people using this when it isn't valid CCS?

They don't know better or they do but really really need to style differently IE10/11 from others or Safari or Chrome or Firefox and they don't want to load Modernizr for just 1 hack (they'd if there were many discrepancies, probably).
Valid CSS is a very fine way of doing your work in a qualitative way but it isn't a goal in itself. Pages won't necessarily break as they would with ill-formed XML.

> Is there a way to make this mixin valid CSS?

What are you trying to achieve? You didn't tell us why you needed to hack styles especially for IE (so many reasons...).
`@supports` or Modernizr could be a better solution, or maybe not: it depends, as usual in the front-end world.

Comment: Thanks for your really helpful reply!
I will drop the mixin and will looking into Modernizer. 
The reason I needed the mixin was because my css animations broke in IE and I wanted to disable them with this mixin. 

Thanks again!